# How to deploy a snippet created in Word scriptlab to word store for individual testing?

Tags: node.js, ms-word, office-js, word-addins, scriptlab

I have created a simple add in for word on scriptlab. Now I would like to deploy it in word store. I don't want to make it public at the moment. I would just like to be able to download my addin from the store and use it in my word (just for myself).

I was reading this document.

https://theofficecontext.com/2018/01/30/yo-create-an-add-in-from-your-script-lab-code/

But in scriptlab, I could find **Export for publishing** after clicking **Share** button (maybe excel and word scriptlab are different). Also, could not find any good source.

Answer (score 1):

There is no longer an **Export for publishing** option in Script Lab. Also, you cannot deploy a private add-in to AppSource (formerly Office Store). For ways to publish your add-in, see [Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish). If you want to use only for yourself, you should use the Network Share method.

Comment: This broken half baked abandon store stuff from MS is gutter trash. After 20 years of avoiding MS this hasn't warmed me to them.